# Finding Schwarzschild Solution

Tags: geodesic, general-relativity, euler-lagrange-equation

> Starting with the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L} = g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu$, derive $4$ equations which govern geodesics in a Schwarzschild spacetime.

My lecturer said that

> If your Euler-Lagrange equation reads
>   $$\large \frac{\mathrm{d}(\text{blah})}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} = 0$$
>   then don't expand it but instead deduce that blah $=$ constant.

But I'm not sure how to process this in such a general setting. Would it be like 
$$\large \mathcal{L} = g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu,\quad \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{x}^\mu}\right) = \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x^\mu}$$
But then why would the RHS be a zero? I'm in need of some assistance.

Comment: This happens when the Lagrangian doesn’t depend on $x^{\mu}$

Comment: So the Lagrangian not depending on $x^\mu$ means that $$\large \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x^\mu} = 0$$ So then, from what I was told, $$\large \text{blah} = \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{x}^\mu} = \text{const.}$$ How would I show this? @Fakemistake

Comment: Integrate with respect to $\lambda$

Comment: @Fakemistake how would $$\large \int\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{x}^\mu}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda = \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{x}^\mu}$$ show that the RHS is constant?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use [Noether's (first) theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem): Since the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$ does not depend explicit on "time" $\lambda$, then the "energy" function 
$$ h~:=~\dot{x}^{\mu} \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial \dot{x}^{\mu}} -{\cal L}~=~\ldots~=~{\cal L} $$
(which happens to be ${\cal L}$ itself!) is constant in "time" along a solution. The above holds even if ${\cal L}$ depends on $x^{\mu}$!

Comment: This is called beltramis identity

Comment: $\uparrow$ Right.